# Django request object created by current user

Tags: django

I am trying to make a query where the current logged in user can view the Teams they have created. Therefore I am trying to print a list of the UserTeams where the UserID = the current user's ID. I know I need to use the 'owner' field i have created for the Teams, though I don't really know where/ what to do.

Here is my view:

```
 def teamsview(request):

     query = UserTeams.objects.filter(userID=request.user)
     return render(request, 'teammanager/teams.html', {
        "teams": query})
```

My Teams and UserTeams models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    venue = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    countryID = models.ForeignKey(Countries, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class UserTeams(models.Model):
    userID = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    teamID = models.ForeignKey(Team,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And my HTML:

```
    {%for team in userteams%}

    <h3><a href='/teams/{{userteam.id}}'>{{team.name}}</a></h3>

    {%endfor%}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need the `UserTeams` model? Your `Team` model already has a foreign key to the `User` model:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    ...
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Therefore, in your view you can do:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def teamsview(request):
    query = Teams.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
    return render(request, 'teammanager/teams.html', {
        "teams": query})
```

The `login_required` decorator makes sure that only logged-in users can access the view.

Then in your template, loop through `teams`, to match the `{"teams": query}` context from your view.

```
{% for team in teams %}

<h3><a href='/teams/{{ team.id }}'>{{team.name}}</a></h3>

{% endfor %}
```